# Jetpack Compose - How to make a keyboard full screen when the screen is in landscape orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Now I am making an app using Jetpack Compose. So I noticed that when the screen is in landscape orientation, the text entry field is hidden by the keyboard, making it difficult to see.

If Jetpack Compose is not used, the keyboard would be displayed across the entire screen when in landscape orientation by default. And I was able to intentionally disable the keyboard to full-screen by putting 'android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"' in EditText.

```
    <EditText
    android:hint="input something"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:inputType="text"/>

    //android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
    //If you don't put this, it will look like this.
```

[image: full screen keyboard]

How do I make a keyboard full screen in Jetpack Compose?

I tried putting

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

in AndroidManifest.xml, but I wasn't able to solve this problem.

Comment: there is an open issue https://issuetracker.google.com/203549026